# How do I add children to a newly created XML node using PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to add children to a newly created node using `addChild()` of simpleXml but it gives me an exception:

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addChild()[simlexmlelement.addchild]: Cannot add child. Parent is not a permanent member of the XML tree in (file address) on line (line number)
```

And I got that multiple times, since the significant part of my code is:

```html
<?php

  $xml = simplexml_load_file(".db.xml") or die("Sorry, no database file found, we will solve it as soon as possible.");

  if($xml->$name->getName() == $name) {
    echo "We're sorry, but this account name already exists. Underneath is a table with your signup data anyways. We also sent you an email if you are going to retry later.";
  } else {
    $xml->db->addChild($name);
    $xml->$name->addChild("email", $email);
    $xml->$name->addChild("day", $day);
    $xml->$name->addChild("month", $month);
    $xml->$name->addChild("year", $year);
  }
?>
```

And this is my prettified XML code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
  <db>
    <example>
      <email>example@email.com</email>
      <day>01</day>
      <month>01</month>
      <year>1975</year>
    </example>
  </db>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

### Note:

I know that the values of the variables are not the problem because all variables show the right values in the table of data that I made for the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the children to a reference like so:

```
$nametag = $xml->db->addChild($name);
$nametag->addChild("email", $email);
$nametag->addChild("day", $day);
$nametag->addChild("month", $month);
$nametag->addChild("year", $year);
```

Read more here: 
http://php.net/manual/ro/simplexmlelement.addchild.php

example nr.1

**Update**

Here the code I tested with output so you can see it actually adds the tags to the final xml structure:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("db.xml") or die("Sorry, no database file found, we will solve it as soon as possible.");
$name = "a";
$email = "b";
$day = "c";
$month = "d";
$year = "e";
if($xml->$name->getName() == $name) {
    echo "We're sorry, but this account name already exists. Underneath is a table with your signup data anyways. We also sent you an email if you are going to retry later.";
} else {
    $tagname = $xml->db->addChild($name);
    $tagname->addChild("email", $email);
    $tagname->addChild("day", $day);
    $tagname->addChild("month", $month);
    $tagname->addChild("year", $year);
}
var_dump($xml->asXML());
```

**Update 2**

To save the xml to a file add at the end:

```
$xml->asXML("db.xml"); // this would overwrite your old file
```

Check this out here:
http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php

Comment: I just tested it and I don't get an error. I have not persisted the xml to check if it indeed saves it but it doesn't yield an error. What is the error you get doing it like this?

Comment: It's true that there are no errors, but it's not uploaded to the file. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: you can just add: $xml->asXML("db.xml"); at the end